# Weird behaviour with OpenVPN: can not connect to a few websites

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

My OpenVPN server is Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS and openvpn version is 2.x

My client is on Win 7. He can access most sites but not Youtube, Facebook, Twitter, groups.google.com, etc

My server.conf is:

```
local x.x.x.x
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status /etc/openvpn/keys/openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

I can access Youtube etc using SSH Tunnel + SOCKS Proxy, and the Ubuntu server can access all sites. so nothing is wrong with the Ubuntu server.

With little information I can provide, I am not looking for a quck solution. How can I debug?

Comment: when using VPN and getting "I can connect to some sites but not others" complaints, I usually start with checking the TCP Maximum Segment Size and tunnel link MTU values.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a link? I am new on MTU and TCP stuff. Do you mean I need to set the TCP/MTU on my server side or client side or both?

Comment: here's some info with explanations of what the parameters do:  http://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-devel/2004-05/msg00027.html

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like an MTU issue. Try setting the MTU of the virtual device to 1300.

I haven't worked with OpenVPN for a while but I think you can just set:

```
tun-mtu 1300
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a link? I am new on MTU stuff. Do you mean I need to set the TCP/MTU on my server side or client side or both?

Comment: Updated answer as requested